# use xgraph or gnuplot in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, gnuplot

I am using ns2.35 and ubuntu 18.040. I have a number of trace files and I want to compare them in terms of: delay, throughput, power consumption (awk files) .. I would like to use xgraph or gnuplot .. Is there an easy way to use them to compare a number of trace files at once?

Comment: Never easy ,,, mostly very complicated `"VIII. Creating Output Files for Xgraph"` http://www.isi.edu/nsnam/ns/tutorial/nsscript4.html ...... "ns2 APP-Tool" can handle raw trace.tr : **1**. http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html ... **2**. 
https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool

Comment: Is there a way to use APP-Tool with more than one tr file?

Comment: I use it, but the problem is that I want to compare several tr files in one xgraph.and this is not possible in the App Tool

Comment: Saved files.txt can be used for gnuplot https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10339733/gnuplot-draw-two-plots-on-the-same-graph-with-single-column-data .... APP-Tool ex https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1AOW_hilzp7LScJ3VtnzZGbMaeOycKoh-?usp=sharing → see 2021 ex with line 1 commented out  ( # ) for use with gnuplot.

Comment: Gnuplot cook book https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big_data_and_business_intelligence/9781849517249/1/ch01lvl1sec12/plotting-multiple-curves

Comment: How can I get awk files that give appropriate results for gnuplot as found in folder 2021?

Comment: The resulting files are "awk outputs" from `APP-Tool/Final/files.awk` . .... In ns-2.35/bin/ there are perl scripts like `raw2xg` etc. to handle trace files. Example using e.g. xgraph_ns2-files-tcl_04.19.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/file/d/1YuW8gmp7GpuibBiZJqj22Gf4ZDIX1gCO/view?usp=sharing